# RewriteRule assistance

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I maintain (system side) an application that utilizes IBM HTP Server and WebSphere Application Server (standalone).  The team wants a change made but I can't figure out what I need to do.

The problem - a users enters 
  http://my-site.com/customerfiles/Client/subdir/file.pdf 
into his/her browser.  The site allows the file to be directly sent to the user, bypassing the application code.  Basically, the pdf file simply gets sent to the browser and opened.  The application team would like the application to get control and send the file back (if the user is authorized to retrieve the file).  Right now, any customer can access any other customers' files.

They would like the above URL redirected to something like 
  siteinfo  `getafile?cust=Client&filetype=subdir&file=file.pdf`

I have a test IHS system that I can play with and have coded

```
RewriteRule ^/customerfiles/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/xs2/getafile?cust={$1}&filetype={$2}&file={$3} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I enabled the RewriteLog feature and these are the messages being issued:

```
10.17.1.163 - - [14/Jul/2015:07:37:02 --0500] [10.17.1.163/sid#474ff0]
[rid#6c1620/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/customerfiles/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$' 
to uri '/customerfiles/Client/subdir/file.pdf'

10.17.1.163 - - [14/Jul/2015:07:37:02 --0500] [10.17.1.163/sid#474ff0]
[rid#6c1620/initial] (1) pass through /customerfiles/Client/subdir/file.pdf
```

I am very much a novice at this and would appreciate help while keeping the solution as a RewriteRule in the configuration file (we don't use .htaccess).

Comment: If any access has to go through the application - why do you keep the file within the webserver-structure at all?

Comment: I don't know why things are set up the way that they are.  It was set up this way over 10 years ago and they now want to have the file(s) served up by their application.  They may not be able to move the files elsewhere - I didn't design the application, I just administer the system.